# Записать переменную в файл для дальнейшего использования

Tags: массивы, php

Доброго вечера. Надеюсь вы посоветуете, как сделать правильнее.

У меня есть массив $params, вот как он выглядит (вывод через print_r($params);)

```
JRegistry Object ( [data:protected] => stdClass Object ( [au_a_logic1] => 2000 [au_a_logic2] => 3000 [au_b_logic1] => 500 [au_b_logic2] => 1000 [au_b_logic3] => 2000 [au_b_logic4] => 5500 [au_b_logic5] => 7500 [au_b_logic6] => 20000 [au_b_logic7] => 50000 [au_b_logic8] => 100000 [au_c_logic1] => 2.5 [au_c_logic2] => 3.5 [au_c_logic3] => 5.5 [au_c_logic4] => 7.5 [au_c_logic5] => 15 [au_c_logic6] => 20 [au_f_logic1] => 0.54 [au_f_logic2] => 0.48 [au_f_logic3] => 0.48 [au_f_logic4] => 0.48 [au_f_logic5] => 0.48 [au_f_logic6] => 0.48 [au_d_logic1] => 1.5 [au_d_logic2] => 1.7 [au_d_logic3] => 2.5 [au_d_logic4] => 2.7 [au_d_logic5] => 3 [au_d_logic6] => 3.6 [au_e_logic1] => 50000 [au_e_logic2] => 50000 [gotoemail] => [jqueryswitch] => 1 [layout] => _:default ) )
```

Я хочу записать массив в файл, а затем использовать его повторно загружая его из файла как готовый массив.

Можно ли так делать, и какими средствами лучше укладывать и считывать из файла?

Comment: сессия не подойдет ? можно ещё json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

с помощью [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.serialize.php) можешь сериализировать и объект и массив, потом сохранить его, достать и распаковать с помощью [unserialize()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.unserialize.php)

Answer (score 0):

Это не массив, это объект, с него ещё массив нужно сделать.
Потом можно этот массив сериализовать в json, например, и записать куда тебе удобно: база или файл.
Где нужно, там потом распарсишь и прочитаешь.

Comment: А записать объектом можно? Мне он нужен в том же виде что есть.